# Automatically start VNC server and terminal on boot

Tags: linux, vnc, vncserver

I am working with Fedora 25 and I am trying to get a VNC server up on every boot with a gnome-terminal running a script inside of it. This can either be done using a cron or rc.d. My goal is to automate the starting of the VNC server with an open terminal already running a script.

Comment: Not that it helps your question but VNC is junk compared to x11 forwarding that has been built into *nix since the beginning.  You should look into it.   You are having to jump through hoops because what you are using isn't native to *nix.

Comment: if your script doesn't need to update the display, better to run the script inside a "screen" or "tmux", and when you log in, just attach to it.